# django submit answer per user

Tags: django, models

I have a text:

```
class QuestionText(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.text)
```

and a Answer:

```
class ElementShortAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(QuestionText)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.answer)
```

How can I add an answer per user. That is, a user ElementShortAnswer has a list of answer for each user.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a User foreign key to `ElementShortAnswer` model and change the question field in ElementShortAnswer model to OneToOne, because every question should be answered once per user.

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and include this line in your ElementShortAnswer class definition -

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to import User too: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662992/django-submit-answer-per-user/37664690))